Understanding ても/でも
I am still struggling to wrap my head around -ても (or でも if it's the て-form of だ).
It mostly makes sense to me if I treat it as "as much" or "even". I am currently trying to SRS learn grammar points with renshuu and they have a lesson where they say でも added to nouns can also mean "or something".
I struggle to see how this can be related to "even". An example sentence they gave is:
コーヒーでも飲みたい。
Translated as: I want to drink coffee or something.
Intuitively I would have translated it as "I want to drink something, even coffee."
This interpretation seems almost opposite to me: "even coffee" implies coffee is less preferred and "coffee or something" that coffee is the most preferred.


Intuitively I would have translated it as "I want to drink something, even coffee." This interpretation seems almost opposite to me: "even coffee" implies coffee is less preferred and "coffee or something" that coffee is the most preferred.

The short version is that preference isn't part of the expressly conveyed nuance; the English is an approximation, because a) it tends to sound really awkward in English if you go out of your way to avoid implying a preference; b) generally the Japanese speaker does have a preference but it's communicated in other ways.

The te-form of a verb is really its i-stem (masu-stem) plus て, then smoothed over with a sound change depending on the final sound. Some of these preserve the て and others voice it to で. We can then follow up with the ordinary particle も.
A noun plus でも is the noun plus で plus も. Whether this で is the particle で or the te-form of だ, is a complicated question. It's not even clear to me that these are especially distinct things in the first place. There's a lot I could say on that topic, and other users here who could elaborate on really interesting historical and etymological detail (some of which I think I even remember accurately). But none of that really matters to the analysis. You arrive at essentially the same meaning, from an English perspective, with either interpretation of the で.
The important point is: in all cases, ても/でも isn't really a single thing, but a combination. But that combination can have the meaning described in the lesson.
Fundamentally, も is simply a non-contrastive topic marker. It fills the same grammatical role as は, but is used for a new topic about which the same claim can be made.
In that light, fundamentally the meaning of コーヒーでも飲みたい is agnostic to that preference: the speaker wishes to drink something, regardless of whether it's coffee. Rather: there's some unspoken thing(s) which the speaker would like to drink, and then coffee is also something the speaker would like to drink.
But, of course, the fact that the speaker chose to mention coffee is meaningful information; humans speaking natural languages don't just say things like that for no reason. (If I said "I have no opinion about Mr. Tanaka" out of nowhere, you would wonder why I didn't say it about someone else instead, right? You would probably start suspecting that I did have some opinion....)
So, the nuance will reveal itself from context. "Just give me anything (to drink), even if it's coffee" would make sense if the speaker were previously told that no tea is available. On the flip side, an interpretation like "I'd like coffee, or a reasonable facsimile" makes more sense when there's no previous mention of beverages and nothing to imply desperation.
An English translation with "even (if)" also tends to make more sense with a negative verb: コーヒーでも飲まない -> "I won't drink it even if it's coffee", i.e. "no matter what you're offering me, I'm not drinking it". Tone of voice can also serve as a clue.

I think a good argument for that the binding particle “〜でも” and “ても” form of “〜だ” are distinct is that one can actually come after the other. One can in theory say “きれいででも好きじゃない。” the same way we can say “美しくてでも好きじゃない”. In this particular usage, clearly the “〜でも” is the binding particle, itself a more emphatic version of “〜も”
